# Selected property of a Map control in Power Apps remains blank

Tags: dictionary, powerapps, powerapps-selected-items

I have created an app with Power Apps for door to door agents using a Map component as the main part. The agent would see a bunch of pins on the map and select a pin nearby. The information behind this pin is then populated in a form next to the map. The datasource is a Sharepoint List.

Setup below is a new simplified version of the app: a screen with two controls:

1. Map (mapTest): source = Sharepoint List with 4 columns (Title, Label, Lat, Long)
2. Label (labelTest): Text property = `mapTest.Selected.Label`

[image: Power Apps Map Control]

When I start the app, the pin is shown, so the data gets fetched from the Sharepoint List.
When I click on the pin, the info card with all values is shown **but the mapTest.Selected value stays blank.**

I'm aware that I should use variables but even then it doesn't work.

The app worked fine for a couple of weeks but since today the *Selected* property of the Map stays blank when I select a pin on the map. I haven't changed anything to the app. I've created a new app to find the cause but no success. Is it possible that Microsoft pushed an update without warning?

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that the onclick events fire both, when a pin is selected and when the map is clicked. It did not use to do so.

We used the "click map" to re-center/zoom and the "select" to pick the information from the Pin. Now it re-centers both when you click a pin and when you click the map (and it does not pick the information from the pin) :(